# Internet explorer make cache always refresh option selected in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

i am developing application in asp.net 3.5, while using this application in internet explorer i want make caches always refresh from server option selected.

You can see attached image for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your meta tag:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Comment: is this browser dependent?